# Using Saxon-ce to display filtered output via a combobox

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to set up a combobox with Saxon-ce whose value filters the display of items in an xml. Here is a sample of the code I have so far.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" 
xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
extension-element-prefixes="ixsl">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- set up combo box -->
<xsl:result-document href="#typeControl">
    <xsl:text>Type: </xsl:text>
    <select class="menuSub_monster" id="typeBox">
        <option value="all" selected="'all'">Unsorted</option>
        <option value="group">Sorted</option>
        <option value="value1">Value1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value2</option>
    </select>
</xsl:result-document>

<!-- inital display -->
<xsl:call-template name="displayTemplates">
    <xsl:with-param name="typeSel" select="'all'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Change display when we change combo box -->
<xsl:template match="select[@id='typeBox']" mode="ixsl:onchange">
<xsl:variable name="control" select="."/>
<xsl:variable name="typeValue" select="ixsl:get($control,'value')" />   

<xsl:call-template name="displayTemplates">
    <xsl:with-param name="typeSel" select="$typeValue"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- display routine -->
<xsl:template name="displayTemplates">
<xsl:param name="typeSel"/>
<xsl:result-document href="#display" method="ixsl:replace-content" >
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$typeSel='all'">
    <xsl:for-each select="templates/template">
    <xsl:sort select="sort_name"/>
    ... CODE FOR DISPLAY
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="$typeSel='group'">
    ... CODE FOR DISPLAY
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:for-each select="templates/template/types[type[text()=$typeSel]]">
    <xsl:sort select="../sort_name"/>
            ...CODE FOR DISPLAY
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</div>  

</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

The issue I am having is calling the template displayTemplates when the combobox changes value. My transition to the context templates/template is not working since this is part of the XML I am calling with this style sheet. However, match="select[@id='typeBox']" sets the context to an object not in the XML. How can I change my context from the combobox to my XML so the for-each statements in the display routine work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:  bind a variable to some node in your XML from which you can successfully navigate to where you need to go.  Then use a reference to that variable to move the context back to the other document. (There may be more elegant ways.)

Comment: Agreed. It's always a good idea to have a global variable `<xsl:variable name="source" select="/"/>` so you can always get back to the principal source document without relying on context.

Comment: Ok. Now for the total naieve question.
I have set the variable as suggested (just after the stylesheet declarations), but I am not sure how to use it to shift the context back in the display template. If I simply change the for-each to <xsl:for-each select="$source"/> it doesn't work.  What am I missing?

Comment: Depending on the shape of your input, you might want something like `<xsl:for-each select="$source//templates/template">` for your iteration.

Comment: Ahhh That was what the problem was. I was putting the double slash before the $source. :/

Comment: Also it looks like setting $source's value to "/" was setting it to the wrong thing. I cludged it by using document(..realtive path to xml..) and now it works great.